# How to parse LLVM GEP instruction in a generic enough way?

Tags: llvm, antlr

so I'm working on a grammar that would allow me to parse simple `LLVM IR` files. Currently I have problems with GEP instructions. For instance:

```
%5 = getelementptr inbounds [2 x i32], [2 x i32]* @values, i64 0, i64 %4
%24 = getelementptr inbounds [8 x [256 x i32]], [8 x [256 x i32]]* @crc_table, i64 0, i64 0, i64 %23
%25 = getelementptr inbounds [8 x [256 x i32]], [8 x [256 x i32]]* @crc_table, i64 0, i64 %20, i64 %23
%26 = getelementptr inbounds [8 x [256 x i32]], [8 x [256 x i32]]* @crc_table, i64 0, i64 %20, i64 3
```

I'd like to have a generic rule that would allow me to understand the order of the elements. For instance, in the first line I have a `number` and a `register` but in the last one I have `number`, `register` and `number`.

Adding a rule with ... `(NUMBER|REGISTER)` ... I think it wouldn't help me to understand the order. I though to add something like

```
NOR: (NUMBER|REGISTER)
    ;
```

and use something `NOR(0)`, `NOR(1)` but I think each time I would have to check if it is a `number` or `register`. How would approach this problem?

Please note that LLVM has a number of other instruction using `number` and `register` so I don't want to have to check for the type each time.

How can I do it?

### Edit

Thanks Mike,
I define `NUMBER` in this way:

```
NUMBER  : ('-')* ([0-9])+
    ;
```

and `REGISTER` in this way

```
REGISTER    : '%'(LETTER|INT|'_'|'.')+
            ;
```

If useful please forget about my other rules, I believe you suggestion is going to be useful anyway. So far I thought to use something like

```
nor : (NUMBER|REGISTER)
    ;
```

I can just iterate over them and use something like `ctx.gep_type().nor().REGISTER() != null` and check if it is a register or a number

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail on your rules (Lexer and parser rules).  It might help to understand what the numbers and registers (for those of us that don't know LLVM).   I suspect that a simple parser rule alternative is the answer, but, not knowing LLVM, or your current rules, it's hard to make a suggestion.

Comment: If I assume "NOR (NUMBER|REGISTER): is supposed to be "NOR: (NUMBER|REGISTER;", then I also suspect that making this a Lexer rule, is part of your problem.  Can you provide more of your grammar (or a pointer to a repo), as well as a brief description of how to interpret the sample input you've provided?

Comment: Each value argument of GEP can be either a NUMBER or a REGISTER. What's your question exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the change of the `NOR` (lexer rule) to `nor` (parser rule), you should be able to do as you suggest; iterate through the `nor` contexts to check for which type was actually there.

I don't know how many variations you might have to cover, so these next alternatives may or may not be practical.  If there are a very limited number of options, you could also do something like:

```
gepRule: 
   // whatever goes before the number or registers (I'll abbreviate as "w") 
     w NUMBER REGISTER # GEP_NR
   | w NUMBER REGISTER NUMBER # GEP_NRN
   // other alternatives
   ;
```

This will generate separate ParserContext classes for each alternative (in this case `GEP_NRContext` and `GEP_NRNContext`).

Based on @arrowd's comment, as well as you comments re: many places allowing numbers or registers, I suspect the `nor` parser rule may be more practical, but thought I'd show the alternative in case each variation needs to be handled a bit differently.  You may even want to give both a shot and see which makes the code in your listeners/visitors easier to manage.

p.s. Changing the `NOR` lexer rule to a `nor` parser rule, probably already made this point, but, before you get too far into things make *sure* you understand the difference between lexer and parser rules, and how they are used by the tokenizer and parser.  ANTLR will seem quite confusing if this is not really clear in your thinking.